# Error in installing Remix-ide: Missing script "build"?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, remix

I want to install remix-ide on ubuntu server v18.04.
I use these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide.git
cd remix-ide
sudo apt install build-essential
npm install
npm rebuild
npm run build && npm run serve
```

and I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "build"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/iotchain/.npm/_logs/2021-09-19T09_14_39_042Z-debug.log
```

My versions:

```
node v12.22.6
npm v7.24.0
Truffle v5.1.31
Solidity v0.5.16
Web3.js v1.2.1
python v3.7
Ganache CLI v6.12.2 
remixd v0.5.2
```

The log file:

```
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
20 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 1ms
21 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
22 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 3ms
23 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
24 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
25 timing npm:load Completed in 25ms
26 timing command:run-script Completed in 6ms
27 verbose stack Error: Missing script: "build"
27 verbose stack
27 verbose stack To see a list of scripts, run:
27 verbose stack   npm run
27 verbose stack     at RunScript.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:104:13)
28 verbose cwd /home/iotchain/remix-ide
29 verbose Linux 4.15.0-154-generic
30 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
31 verbose node v12.22.6
32 verbose npm  v7.24.0
33 error Missing script: "build"
33 error
33 error To see a list of scripts, run:
33 error   npm run
34 verbose exit 1
```

Any feedback how to fix the problem?

Comment: why don't you download the release version here: https://github.com/ethereum/remix-desktop/releases/tag/v1.3.2

Comment: Can you upload the complete log to make to accessible? The lines copied in the question aren't enough to determine what is failing.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question @Ismael

Comment: @Helo Still not enough.